# Natural Language Processing books or resource for entry level person?

Tags: nlp

Can anyone gives some suggestions for good natural language processing book. Following are the factors I have in mind:

- It gives a good overview of these huge topics without too much depth.
- Concepts need to explain in picture form.
- Sample code in JAVA/Python/R.

Comment: This is a very good book for Java developer [Natural Language Processing with Java](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/natural-language-processing-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at online courses about NLP. They oftain contain videos, exercices, writing documents, suggested readings...

I especially like this one : https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp (see suggested readings section for instance). You can access the lectures here : https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture (pdf + video + subtitles).

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are three options for you--I wrote one of them so take this with a grain of salt.

1) Natural Language Processing with Python 
by Steven Bird et al. http://amzn.com/0596516495. This book covers using the NLP api NLTK and is considered a solid book for intro to NLP. Lots of code, a more academic take on what NLP is and I assume broadly used in undergraduate NLP classes.

2) Natural Language Processing with Java by Richard Reese http://amzn.to/1D0liUY. This covers a range of APIs, including LingPipe below, and introduces NLP concepts and how they are implemented in a range of open source APIs. It is a more shallow dive into NLP but it is a gentler introduction and it covers how a bunch of APIs solve the same problem so it may help you pick what API to use.

3) Natural Language Processing with Java and LingPipe Cookbook by Breck Baldwin (me) and Krishna Dayanidhi http://amzn.to/1MvgHxa. This is meant for industrial programmers and it covers the concepts common in commercial NLP applications. The book is a much deeper dive into evaluation, problem specification, varied technologies that on the face do the same thing. But it expects you to learn from examples (overwhelmingly Twitter data).

All the books have lots of code, one in Python, the other two in Java. Both present mature APIs with a large installed base.

None of the books do much in the way of graphical explanation of what the software is doing.

Good luck